# Logo printed on fabric

Tags: print-design

I am a new fashion designer and would like to have my logo printed on my designs.How do I print my logo on my clothing designs please? Some are cotton others are a stretch fabric. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Dee, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. As-is, your question is very vague and broad. Could you please specify what you want to ask that you can't find with a Google search or a phone call to your printer of choice? Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Like Vincent mentioned, it really depends on your needs (quantity needed, cost, complexity of design, number of colours etc) and the capabilities of your printer. You can see a quick breakdown of techniques available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_printing#Methods_of_printing). I would direct you to the Screen Printing section.

> Screen printing is by far the most common technology today. Two types
>   exist: rotary screen printing and flat (bed) screen printing. A blade
>   (squeegee) squeezes the printing paste through openings in the screen
>   onto the fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your logo is vector. Take the file on a USB to a screen printer in your area and talk to them about options (mention you'll use your own material and talk about your worries about the temperature of the dryers they use to dry the ink).

IMO you want to find someone who can screen print waterbased inks. Plastisol inks wear off over time and don't look as cool as waterbased.